# Is possible to submit button be at aright side of input, not below?

Tags: html, css

Is possible to submit button be at aright side of input, not below ?
In code I copied form

```
<form action="/city" method="post">
    <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" placeholder="City Name">
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Create New City">
</form>
```

but button `Create New City` is always below.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with javascript or jQuery. Please tag your questions appropriately, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried moving the submit button inside the `<fieldset>` element?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I have tried  that but it is again below, just different size

Answer (score 4):

If you can't amend the HTML, try adding this CSS to your page:

```
fieldset {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rnk5Z/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/city" method="post">
    <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" placeholder="City Name">
        <input type="submit" value="Create New City">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please write what is the change!

Comment: @MohamedSakherSawan He's put the submit `input` element inside the `fieldset`

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
<form action="/city" method="post">
<fieldset data-role="fieldcontain" style='display: inline'>
    <input type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" placeholder="City Name">
</fieldset>
<input style='display: inline' type="submit" value="Create New City">
</form>
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/cMec8/)

Answer (score 1):

add the following css

```
fieldset
    {
        display: inline;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tYsTd/